# Is there a way in MySQL to use aggregate functions in a sub section of binary column?

Tags: mysql, database, postgresql

Suppose we have 2 numbers of 3 bits each attached together like '101100', which basically represents 5 and 4 combined. I want to be able to perform aggregation functions like SUM() or AVG() on this column separately for each individual 3-bit column.

For instance:

'101100'

'001001'

sum(first three column) = 6

sum(last three column) = 5

I have already tried the SUBSTRING() function, however, speed is the issue in that case as this query will run on millions of rows regularly. And string matching will slow the query.

I am also open for any new databases or technologies that may support this functionality.

Comment: Is there a reason that the two numbers are in the same field? Is changing your schema to have them in separate fields an option?

Comment: Yes, it is for a reason because the number of columns are variable due to the nature of the application. If not combined, the number of columns reach the maximum limit allowed for a table (i.e. 1500 columns).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the function [`conv()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_conv) to convert any part of the string to a decimal number:

```
select 
  sum(conv(left(number, 3), 2, 10)) firstpart,
  sum(conv(right(number, 3), 2, 10)) secondpart            
from tablename
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/V5GbM84Cjmuf5xYzDe7Wb/0).
Results:

```
| firstpart | secondpart |
| --------- | ---------- |
| 6         | 5          |
```

Comment: This works perfectly for the solution, however, left() and right() will have similar speed constraint as SUBSTRING() function right?

Comment: I guess, although I did not test it.

Answer (score 1):

With the current understanding I have of your schema (which is next to none), the best solution would be to restructure your schema so that each data point is its own record instead of all the data points being in the same record. Doing this allows you to have a dynamic number of data points per entry. Your resulting table would look something like this:

```
id | data_type | value
```

ID is used to tie all of your data points together. If you look at your current table, this would be whatever you are using for the primary key. For this answer, I am assuming `id INT NOT NULL` but yours may have additional columns.

Data Type indicates what type of data is stored in that record. This would be the current tables column name. I will be using `data_type_N` as my values, but yours should be a more easily understood value (e.g. `sensor_5`).

Value is exactly what it says it is, the value of the data type for the given id.  Your values appear to be all numbers under 8, so you could use a `TINYINT` type. If you have different storage types (`VARCHAR`, `INT`, `FLOAT`), I would create a separate column per type (`val_varchar`, `val_int`, `val_float`).

The primary key for this table now becomes a composite: `PRIMARY KEY (id, data_type)`. Since your previously single record will become N records, the primary key will need to adjust to accommodate that.

You will also want to ensure that you have indexes that are usable by your queries.

Some sample values (using what you placed in your question) would look like:

```
1 | data_type_1 | 5
1 | data_type_2 | 4
2 | data_type_1 | 1
2 | data_type_2 | 1
```

Doing this, summing the values now becomes trivial. You would only need to ensure that `data_type_N` is summed with `data_type_N`. As an example, this would be used to sum your example values:

```
SELECT data_type,
    SUM(value)
FROM my_table
WHERE id IN (1,2)
GROUP BY data_type
```

[Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2316ae/2/0) is an SQL Fiddle showing how it can be used.

Comment: Hi Jacob, this is our backup solution, however, this suffers in performance due to multiple inner joins, we will have to perform for selecting data from a single response.

Comment: @DivyanshuChauhan I don't think you will need to do any joins. Please see my update on how a table like this is to be used.